# PHP Variable inside array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable:

```
$my_var = page
```

And want to put it into an array:

```
 <?php 
    $opts = array(
        'page'=>'/subfolder/ <!-- $my_var ---> .php',
    );
    content_custom('content-area', $opts); 
?>
```

That I will get the path like:

```
/subfolder/page.php
```

I'm not so familiar with php. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$opts = array(
    'page'=>"/subfolder/{$my_var}.php"
);
```

Comment: @Melros no problem ^_^ happy to help

Answer (score 3):

That will work fine. However, when you put a string in SINGLE quotes, variables inside it aren't evaluated. Use double quotes around the variable you're including in the string, and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the . operator to concatenate strings:

Neal's example:

```
$opts = array(
    'page'=>'/subfolder/'.$my_var.'.php'
);
```